# how to connect at Sql server database using Xamarin cross platform(android,ios,uwp) application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin.forms

need some help, I'm working with Xamarin cross-platform application I'm trying to connect to SQL server database. but an error occurs when I open the connection..

```
public SqlConnection GetSqlConn(DbCredentials d)
    {
        try
        {

            dbconn = new SqlConnection();
            string str = @"server=" + d.server + "; user=" + d.user + "; password=" + d.password + "; database=" + d.dbName + "; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout=" + 7;
            dbconn.ConnectionString = str;

           dbconn.Open();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;

        }
        return dbconn;
    }


public class DbCredentials
{
    public string server { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string dbName { get; set; }


}
```

at `dbconn.Open();` it has an error says

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS7069  Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in
>   'System', but it could not be
>   found DbConnection    C:\Users\Julie\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\DbConnection\DbConnection\DbConnection\Class\DbConnection.cs    44  Active

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you using the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace to access the `SqlConnection` class ?

Comment: The error says that it can't find [System.ComponentModelComponent](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.ComponentModel.Component/) which is defined in `System.dll`. Are you missing a reference perhaps?

Comment: @DavidPilkington i'm using system.data.sqlclient

Comment: I'm trying to add system.dll to reference but it say's (this component is already automatically referenced by the build system) @PanagiotisKanavos